# Nonisomorphic free ultrafilters on $\omega$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

Any bijection from $\Bbb N$ to itself transforms an ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$ to another (isomorphic) ultrafilter.  Any two principal ultrafilters are isomorphic in that sense.

For free ultrafilters on $\Bbb N$, there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ of them.  Since there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ bijections of $\Bbb N$ to itself, there are also $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ isomorphism classes of free ultrafilters on $\Bbb N$.  So lots of free ultrafilters must be nonisomorphic to each other.

**Question:** Can you give an explicit example or construction of two free ultrafilters on $\Bbb N$ that are not isomorphic?  Assume ZFC.

(Added at the suggestion of @bof in the comments below, in case the question proves too difficult to answer directly):

> 1. Give an explicit example of two filters such that no free ultrafilter extending one of them can be isomorphic to a free ultrafilter extending the other.
> 2. Can you state a property, preserved by isomorphism, possessed by some but not all free ultrafilters?

(1) is as good as the original question as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @bof . The existence of a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$ cannot be done without the Axiom of Choice, so in a sense there is no explicit example, as it is also consistent with ZF that they don't exist.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by an explicit example since even exhibiting a single nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$ is rather nonexplicit, but what you call being isomorphic is usually called being Rudin-Keisler equivalent. The RK-order has been (is being) extensively studied and there are plenty of results from the 70/80s constructing large families of RK-incomparable ultrafilters on $\omega$. In J. van Mill's chapter on *The Handbook of Set Theoretic Topology* you can find the construction of two RK-incomparable ultrafilters on $\omega$. Would you count it as explicit?

Comment: To add to the comment by @AlessandroCodenotti, you might also want to look at combinatorial properties such as p-points, q-points, etc., as well as rapid filters for (1),  While it is consistent that no such ultrafilter exists, it is still a way to find a reasonable condition. (I should add that I know very little about these questions, but these are keyword for you to start your journey with.)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti and Asaf: I was hoping there would something simple, but that may turn out to be elusive.  Thanks for the references and background info.

Comment: There is a product operation on ultrafilters. Ultrafilters that have square roots are not isomorphic to those that haven't.

Comment: p-points are the minimal elements in the RK-order if they exist, so any pair of ultrafilters with one being a p-point and one not being a p-point is an easy example answering your question, but examples can be constructed in ZFC directly as I mentioned above. I don't know if there are easy ZFC examples though. Blass is the expert on those things, hopefully he'll see the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest property that I can think of (right now) that provably (in ZFC) distinguishes some non-principal ultrafilters on $\mathbb N$ from others is "weak P-point", which means "not in the closure in $\beta\mathbb N$ of a countable set of other non-principal ultrafilters." The existence of weak P-points is a theorem of Kunen; the existence of non-principal ultrafilters that are not weak P-points is trivial (take any countably infinite set of non-principal ultrafilters and take any other point in their closure).

Comment: Thanks!  Would you have a reference for weak P-points?

Comment: http://ktiml.mff.cuni.cz/~verner/download/ultrafilters_and_independent_systems.pdf has a good overview

Comment: If I understand you correctly, since $\beta \Bbb  N$ \ $\Bbb N$ has no isolated points, this result of Kunen is that $\beta \Bbb N$ \ $\Bbb N$ is not a space of countable tightness.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Kunen's result looks a bit stronger than "not of countable tightness" to me. A counterexample to countable tightness would be a point p that is in the closure of a set A but not in the closure of any countable subset of A. Such a point p could still be in the closure of a countable set disjoint from A, so it might fail to be a weak P-point.

Comment: Yes I see. Stronger.